# Navigation within section of a page using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have my navigation bar with following contents

```
+------+-------+-------+
| Home | About | Login |
+------+-------+-------+
```

Home is **vertically scroll-able page with multiple sections** (e.g `#About` and other sections) While login is separate react component which gets rendered on `/login` route.

Here is my `route.js` file

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
</Route>
```

My question is how should I handle navigational changes within page sections?

Currently I am doing it like this:

```
<li>
    <Link to="/#about-us">About</Link>
</li>
```

and **About** section within **home** page is

```
<div id="about-us">
    About us
</div>
```

Problem with this approach is when I am at login page(`/login`) and click on About section link (`/#about-us`) of Home page nothing happens!

**Edit:**
I am using **react-routerV2**

Answer (score 0):

React Router currently does not handle scroll behavior for hash anchors.

However, if you're using browser history, in your case, you can just use `<a href="#about-us">`, and let the browser take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem! The fix I'm using is below...

```
animatedScroll: function(div_to_scroll_to) {
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: div_to_scroll_to.offset().top
  }, 500);
}
```

Clicking the About link should trigger an `onClick` event which calls `animatedScroll` with the div you want to scroll to (which is a jQuery element in the above code) as the parameter.

This avoids page reloads (which is how the `<a href="..." ...` fix would work) and requires very little work on your part.

Hopefully the React-Router team will have built handlers for intra-component navigation soon.

Good luck!

**Note:** Depending on how your page is structured `jQuery('html, body')` may not be appropriate. This should always just be the parent container. Please let me know if you have any further questions.