# What is the use of scroll behavior mentioned in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was trying to upgrade to latest react-router. While reading the upgrade guide I found this "`Using Scroll Behavior`" and Below code snippet

```
import { Router, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import useScroll from 'scroll-behavior/lib/useStandardScroll';

const appHistory = useScroll(useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory))();
<Router history={appHistory}/>
```

What is the use of scroll behaviour in react-router? I didn't see its much reference in docs. Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: I didn't know this feature existed and it looks like many people have had issues with it in different browsers.  I'm pretty sure this is trying to give a hint to react-router about what to do if you change route and you want to maintain scroll position.

Comment: If it is that then It will solve my old question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946735/navigation-within-section-of-a-page-using-react-router

Comment: Just because it will maintain previous scroll position, doesn't necessarily mean that it will navigate to an anchor, but worth a try :)