# In react router v4 how does one link to a fragment identifier?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Given the very simple page (having assumed React and react-router@4 have been imported):

```
// Current location: example.com/about
<Link to="/about/#the-team">See the team</Link>
// ... loads of content ... //
<a id="the-team"></a>
```

I would expect the above, upon clicking "See the team" would scroll down to the id'ed team anchor. The url correctly updates to: `example.com/about#the-team`, but it doesn't scroll down.

I have tried alternatives such as `<a name="the-team"></a>` but I believe this is no longer spec (nor does it work).

There are plenty of work arounds on github for react-router@v2 but they rely on the update callback present on BrowserRouter that is no longer present in v4.

Comment: Here did you try this? https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link-scroll which depends upon the browser history,if it solves your problem i'll update my answer

Comment: Looks like it relies on react router @v2 ?

Comment: try if it works,maybe as it depends only on the browserHistory,to redirect to the following hash

Comment: The issue being that React Router v4 doesn't have onUpdate callbacks

Comment: oh ok i'll try to figure out something else

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/394#issuecomment-141526205 posted by alansouzati doesnt use update Callbacks and this link https://github.com/metabase/metabase/pull/1555 using the element `.scrollIntoView()` might be able to help you

Comment: Have to tried this https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll ?

Comment: Since a year has passed from the discussion, so are there any changes in approach? What's currently preferable way to work around with this bug in React Router currently as  v4.2.2 ? Because authors seems don't suggest it as an issue any more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given a `<ScrollIntoView>` component which takes the id of the element to scroll to:

```
class ScrollIntoView extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.scroll()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.scroll()
  }

  scroll() {
    const { id } = this.props
    if (!id) {
      return
    }
    const element = document.querySelector(id)
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

You could either wrap the contents of your view component in it:

```
const About = (props) => (
  <ScrollIntoView id={props.location.hash}>
    // ...
  </ScrollIntoView>
)
```

Or you could create a match wrapper:

```
const MatchWithHash = ({ component:Component, ...props }) => (
  <Match {...props} render={(props) => (
    <ScrollIntoView id={props.location.hash}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </ScrollIntoView>
  )} />
)
```

The usage would be:

```
<MatchWithHash pattern='/about' component={About} />
```

A fully fleshed out solution might need to consider edge cases, but I did a quick test with the above and it seemed to work.

#### Edit:

This component is now available through npm. GitHub: https://github.com/pshrmn/rrc

```
npm install --save rrc

import { ScrollIntoView } from 'rrc'
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the answer but the edge cases are really what I am looking for. The above operates no differently to the my answer below I believe

Comment: I added a `componentDidUpdate` function to the `<ScrollTo>` component which allows it to handle scrolling to the hash id element within a loaded page. This also should not break `<Miss>` because it does not register a false match (the wildcard `<Match>` that the other answer gives).

Comment: Ah I see. You would need to wrap each route with this HOC is that right? Also, I don't believe `componentShouldUpdate` can be relied on because it won't trigger if the same link is clicked twice (as there would be no change) - for example, clicking "#About us" scrolls down to about us section, manually scroll back up, click "#About us" again, and nothing happens. Though I think this approach is getting us closed.

Comment: There actually is a change when clicking a `<Link>` to the same location. This is because the browser history creates a new key for every location that is pushed to it.

Comment: Thats interesting. Is that passed down through as context?

Comment: The router components listen for history changes so whenever the `history` receives a new location, the `<Router>` (and all of its children) will re-render. There is also a subscription model that is used to get around `shouldComponentUpdate` issues, but that isn't necessary for most updates.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for v4 specific to the re-render of the children or the subscription model? From the reading I have done, I thought they were dropping a lot of that in v4. Thanks

Comment: The subscription model only exists because if a component that is a parent to a `<Match>` doesn't update because of `shouldComponentUpdate` the component won't be matched to the new location. The main use case for this is redux connected components. I don't think that this is documented because it should all be handled internally (and also because v4 is still in alpha).

Comment: I've finally got around to testing this in depth today... It's working really well so far! Would you be opposed if I (or you) created a more fleshed out version on GH?

Comment: Feel free to create your own, but I also published a version of this to NPM. The github repo is visible through npm if there are any issues or PRs. I need to write some tests to validate everything is working, but it should be good to go.

Comment: Cool, I'd much rather submit a PR over starting something anew. Once you feel comfortable with public view can you add a link here? Either npm or github? Thanks again

Comment: Don't you need `hash.substr(1)`, since it includes the `#`?

Comment: are you serious right now dude? `const element = document.querySelector(id)` should be `const element = document.querySelector(\`#${id}\`)`

Answer (score 2):

The react-router team seem to be actively tracking this issue (at the time of writing v4 isn't even fully released).

As a temporary solution, the following works fine.

**EDIT 3** This answer can now be safely ignored with the accepted answer in place. Left as it tackles the question slightly differently.

**EDIT2** The following method causes other issues, including but not limited to, clicking Section A, then clicking Section A again doesn't work. Also doesn't appear to work with any kind of animation (have a feeling with animation starts, but is overwritten by a later state change)

**EDIT** Note the following does screw up the Miss component. Still looking for a more robust solution

```
// App
<Router>
    <div>
        <Match pattern="*" component={HashWatcher} />

        <ul>
            <li><Link to="/#section-a">Section A</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/#section-b">Section B</Link></li>
        </ul>


        <Match pattern="/" component={Home} />

    </div>
</Router>


// Home 
// Stock standard mark up
<div id="section-a">
    Section A content
</div>
<div id="section-b">
    Section B content
</div>
```

Then, the HashWatcher component would look like the following. It is the temp component that "listens" for all route changes

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class HashWatcher extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        if(this.props.location.hash !== "") {
            this.scrollToId(this.hashToId(this.props.location.hash));
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        // Reset the position to the top on each location change. This can be followed up by the
        // following hash check.
        // Note, react-router correctly sets the hash and path, even if using HashHistory
        if(prevProps.location.pathname !== this.props.location.pathname) {
            this.scrollToTop();
        }

        // Initially checked if hash changed, but wasn't enough, if the user clicked the same hash 
        // twice - for example, clicking contact us, scroll to top, then contact us again
        if(this.props.location.hash !== "") {
            this.scrollToId(this.hashToId(this.props.location.hash));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the leading # on the hash value
     * @param  string hash
     * @return string
     */
    hashToId(hash) {
        return hash.substring(1);
    }

    /**
     * Scroll back to the top of the given window
     * @return undefined
     */
    scrollToTop() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Scroll to a given id on the page
     * @param  string id The id to scroll to
     * @return undefined
     */
    scrollToId(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
    }

    /**
     * Intentionally return null, as we never want this component actually visible.
     * @return {[type]} [description]
     */
    render() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some info about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681051/what-is-the-use-of-scroll-behavior-mentioned-in-react-router

Answer (score 2):

I've created a library called [react-scroll-manager](https://github.com/trevorr/react-scroll-manager) that addresses this issue and the other issues around scroll position with React Router. It uses [this technique](https://medium.com/@gajus/making-the-anchor-links-work-in-spa-applications-618ba2c6954a) to navigate to hash links anywhere in the document without the need to wrap them individually. Simply wrap your Router component in a ScrollManager component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.history = createHistory();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollManager history={this.history}>
        <Router history={this.history}>
          ...
        </Router>
      </ScrollManager>
    );
  }
}
```

You can link to any component with an `id` property:

```
<MyComponent id="mycomp">...</MyComponent>
```

Just include the `id` as a fragment in your Link target:

```
<Link to="#mycomp">...</Link>
```

The library is based on HTML5 and React 16, and it supports React Router 4 (and possibly earlier versions).